# Weird reflections on glass bottle render with cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, glass, reflection

If you look at this PNG you notice this "reflection" near the bottom of this bottle. Why is that so hard? Where does it come from? from the bottle itself?

[image]

I rendered it a couple of times, I increased the area lightings like crazy, deleted objects from the scene, all lights aren´t viewable in renders and viewport. no changes at all....

I also checked the world environment, changed a HDRI (indoor studio light 4k)

The only thing I notice is, when I am Changing the camera perspective, then this stuff changes the position.

Comment: The reflections come from objects and lights in the scene and the image used as the environment in the world. You have to be more strategic when it comes to lighting shiny objects. Get rid of the HDRi first, and place a single area light and play with it until you find the angle that suits your purposes in terms of showing the shape of your object and pay special attention on how it is being reflected on the surface. Only then start adding more lights and see the effect on the image. There are countless pages on the internet on how to light glass objects.

Comment: https://learn.zoner.com/how-to-photograph-shiny-products-and-glass-products/ and https://savageuniversal.com/blog/an-intro-to-photographing-bottles/

Comment: thanks susu! 

I thought about the "light" object of that HDRi. But not finished my thoughts obviously. 

Well.. thank you so much for that quick help. I will try to set the light without the hdri :) 

And thanks for the link ! Really appreciate it :)

Comment: Anytime youi are dealing with highly reflective objects you are not lighting the object per se, but creating a pattern of reflections.